# Evaluation the limit $T= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+2\sin 2x }{2x + \cos x +2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$T = \lim_{x \to \infty}  \frac{x+2\sin 2x }{2x + \cos x +2}$$

After using L'Hopital I have $$T = \lim_{x \to \infty}  \frac{1+ 4\cos 2x}{2 - \sin x} .$$ I don't what to do next, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
    T=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x+2\sin{2x}}{2x+\cos{x}+2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{2\sin{2x}}{x}}{2+\frac{\cos{x}}{x}+\frac{2}{x}}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Instead of applying l'Hôpital's Rule, observe that the function can be bounded by rational functions as
$$\frac{x - 2}{2 x + 3} \leq \frac{x + 2 \sin 2 x}{2 x + \cos x + 2} \leq \frac{x + 2}{2 x + 1} .$$
Now, apply the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would explain their objection (to what seems like a routine answer) so that it can be improved?